# Symfony how override fosrestbundle

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I need to override fosrestbundle/Controller/ExceptionController.
For that i have created an controller :

```
class ExceptionApiController extends ExceptionController
{

    public function showAction(Request $request, $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $response = parent::showAction();

    }
}
```

But how use $response ? How add value in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to create a new UserBundle, and extend FOSUserbundle:

```
namespace UserBundle;

use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Creating a "ExceptionController" class into UserBundle, will override the one from FOSUserBundle.